# Overriding parent class with Zend\Di

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm introducing myself to dependency injection (in my case it is Zend\Di). I don't know what I'm getting wrong but I cannot find how to override a parent class. Let's say we have three classes A, B and C:

```
class A implements C {
...
}

class B extends A implements C {
...
}

interface C {
...
}
```

Now, I want to create a custom class D which changes some functionality implemented in A:

```
class D extends A {
//override A's required methods
}
```

What I need to do now is, via dependency injection, make sure B extends from D instead of A, so it inherits those overriden methods. I need to do it via Di configuration so I think it shoud be something like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'definition' => [
        'class' => [
            'My_Namespace\D' => [
                'supertypes' => ['Base_Namespace\A'] /*it needs to be an array*/
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I'm testing this in two different cases and either this configuration does nothing (B keeps inheriting A methods) or I get an error while calling a constructor which needs B (Argument passed must be an instance of B, string given).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But `B` **does not** extend `D`. It extends `A`. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but it seems you're not getting DI concept here.

Comment: I know this might not be the best approach. The thing is A, B and C are classes I cannot change at all. I'm only allowed to change the behaviour extending those classes into custom classes.

Comment: You just cannot put `D` **between** `B` and `A` in inheritance hierarchy. This does not have anything to DI, it's against OOP in general. As I understand, you cannot touch `A`, `B` and `C`, but `D` is your class, so since you know how `B` looks, you should simply do `D extends B` and do not override `B`'s methods which should stay as they are.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer